# Is SourceGear Vault free?

Tags: sourcegear-vault

Is sourcegear vault free? if its not what is the restrictions in a trial if they are available?

Comment: why not going on their website?

Comment: Another option is Perforce (www.perforce.com), they are free for a server with a max of 2 users (ie: home use). Additionally if you are working on a Open Source project, you can apply to get as many user licenses as you need for free. IMHO it is more robust/scalable and platform independent than Vault. (the server can be hosted on windows/linux/mac/unix and the client tools can be on any of those platforms as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NM i found it:

http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/documentation/pricing.html

sorry

Answer (score 3):

It's **free for single users** as their home page says:

> Try Vault For Free
>
> A full-featured 30-day evaluation is
>   available at no charge — and Vault **is
>   always free for single users.**
>
> Just download Vault, install it in a
>   few minutes, and give it a "try before
>   you buy".

http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/index.html

But if you need more than a single copy, you'll need to purchase licenses.

Answer (score 1):

It costs [$299](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/documentation/pricing.html)